# Start Path of RoundRect with DashPathEffect from center

Tags: java, android, graphics, android-graphics

I'm trying to draw a progress path using a DashPathEffect and path with a round rect. Every time a I get a progress update I update the path using the phase.

```
  private void updatePath(float phase) {
    path.reset();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    rect.inset(progressInset, progressInset);
    path.addRoundRect(rect, progressRadius, progressRadius, Path.Direction.CW);

    PathMeasure pathMeasure = new PathMeasure(path, false);
    length = pathMeasure.getLength();

    intervals[0] = length;
    intervals[1] = length;

    PathEffect effect = new DashPathEffect(intervals, phase);

    paint.setPathEffect(effect);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
```

This looks like this:
[Progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqy0O.png)

However the path starts to draw from the center left of the shape; was wondering if it possible to start drawing the path from the center top of the shape without rotating the shape. I've tried moveTo which doesn't seem to work? Any suggestions on how to make the starting point of the path to be the center middle ?